# Нахождение несобственного интеграла в Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Использую функцию scipy.integrate.quad для нахождения несобственного интеграла от -inf до некоторого значения a, подынтегральная функция - ф.п.в. обобщенного логистического распределения, однако в ходе решения выдает ошибку следующего рода: "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp return np.log(c) - x - (c+1.0)*sc.log1p(np.exp(-x)). Прошу помочь понять, почему выдается данное предупреждение и как можно решить эту ошибку.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.stats as sts
import numpy as np

fx = sts.genlogistic
c, loc, scale = 1.112, -0.0059, 0.03108
a = 13.6e-5
def f(x, c, loc, scale, a):
    return (a-x)**2 * fx.pdf(x, c=c, loc=loc, scale=scale)

print(quad(f, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(c, loc, scale, a)))
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp in computing the logistic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26218617/4279)

Comment: спасибо, я это уже смотрел, однако у меня не получается взять интеграл с помощью функции scipy.integrate.quad следующего вида:     def pdf(x, a, loc, scale):
        return (2*scale*np.exp(-scale*(x-loc))) / (np.square(1+np.exp(-scale*(x-loc)))*(1+np.exp(-a*scale*(x-loc))))

Comment: это асимметричное логистическое распределение (параметры по умолчанию: a=0, loc=0, scale=1)

Comment: в вопросе вы пишите что даже не понимайте откуда предупреждение берётся. По ссылке явно это объясняется и предлагаются пару альтернатив. Если они не работают в вашем случае,  о явно прямо в вопросе упомяните: что конкретно пробовали и как именно сломалось.

Comment: он пишет что ошибка может быть занижена. Если бы я понял как это исправить, я бы не писал сюда. Поэтому и прошу помочь

Comment: ясно ли вам почему: `numpy.exp(1e3)` предупреждение печатает?

Comment: я конечно недавно программирую на питоне (раньше был вольфрам), но могу предположить, что это как то связано с плавающей точкой